# Auto Import Excel into phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql, database, import, phpmyadmin

I want to import excel sheet into database through a web page.

For example- Admin can import the excel sheet into database like uploading a simple file.

I have searched throughout the stack overflow but unable to find any solution.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: it at  all possible, go the csv route, its much easier -[phpExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) if you cant.

Comment: @Deadlock Did u find a method to implement this? I hope you are looking for a method where when a admin presses button or something in the web site the database would go into a excel sheet ?

Comment: @sam_rox I opted for csv route. Its much easier to follow and implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible solutions are:

1. Convert your excel file into CSV format. You can easily parse this Comma separated ASCII file using any server side scripting language such as PHP, JSP etc. and prepare appropriate queries to insert these fileds in the database.
2. If you dont want to convert the Excel file to CSV then u need to use some APIs like Apache POI and Java Servlet/JSP programming clubbed with JDBC to put your data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Export your spreadsheet as a CSV format and use the phpMyAdmin "Import" tab to import this file. You will need to match up the columns in your spreadsheet to the fields in the database table.

Comment: I don't want to give phpmyadmin access to anyone, that's why I wanted to use form like web page to do all this via php